# How to filter item from NSObject Array

Tags: swift, uitableview, filter, uisearchbar

Below is my 2 Objects

**Muscle**

```
struct MuscleListObject {
    var strMuscleName: String = ""
    var arrMuscleExercise: [MuscleExerciseListObject] = []
}
```

**ExerciseObject**

```
struct MuscleExerciseListObject {
    var strExerciseName: String  = ""
}
```

I know the Muscle wise filter but i want to search item exercise wise. how can I do this? please guid me about this.

```
arrSearchedMuscle = self.arrExercise.filter({ objMuscle in
    if let name = objMuscle.strMuscleName as? String, let query = searchBar.text {
        return name.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
    }
    return false
})
```

**EDIT**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.count == 0 {
            isSearching = false
            arrSearchedMuscle = arrExercise
        }
        else {
            isSearching = true

            let query = searchText
            arrSearchedMuscle = arrExercise.compactMap { category -> MuscleListObject? in
                if category.strMuscleName.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil {
                    return category
                } else {
                    arrSearchedExercise = category.arrMuscleExercise.filter({ $0.strExerciseName.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil  })
                    if arrSearchedExercise.isEmpty {
                        return nil
                    } else {
                        let newCategory = category
                        newCategory.arrMuscleExercise = arrSearchedExercise
                        return newCategory
                    }
                }
            }
            print(arrExercise)
            print(arrSearchedMuscle)
        }
        self.tblVWExercise.reloadData()
    }
```

Please guide me about the filter call.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use class. Use struct

Comment: @RajeshKumarR, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Muscle title contains search query return whole Muscle object. If not filter Exercise objects with search query and return updated Muscle object. If particular Muscle object doesn't contain search query return nil

```
let query = "band"
arrSearchedMuscle = arrExercise.compactMap { category -> MuscleListObject? in
    if category.strMuscleName.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil {
        return category
    } else {
        let filteredItems = category.arrMuscleExercise.filter({ $0.strExerciseName.range(of: query, options: [.caseInsensitive]) != nil  })
        if filteredItems.isEmpty {
            return nil
        } else {
            var newCategory = category
            newCategory.arrMuscleExercise = filteredItems
            return newCategory
        }
    }
}
print(arrExercise)
print(arrSearchedMuscle)
```

[image]

Comment: This code works fine but when I search something, the result is fine but when I remove last character some items are missing from my main array `arrExercise`

Comment: When searchBar.text is empty  arrSearchedMuscle = arrExercise

Comment: I have tried this but still result is mismatched while removing last character. updated my question with my SearchBar delegate.

Comment: @Kuldeep Have you used arrSearchedMuscle in tableview datasource methods?

Comment: yes I have used `arrSearchedMuscle`. I load different data as per `isSearching` flag. If user searched anything then I load data from `arrSearchedMuscle` other wise load data from `arrExercise`.

Comment: I think main `arrExercise` data changed because of this line. `newCategory.arrMuscleExercise = arrSearchedExercise`

Comment: When it founds the typed object, above line replace the previous object with newly found object.

Comment: @Kuldeep Struct is value type. So when you change newCategory.arrMuscleExercise = arrSearchedExercise, it doesn't change anything in arrExercise. But changes from a copy of arrExercise. Have you changed class to struct in your project also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192567/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-kuldeep).